# how can i set data traffic limit for per user ? (based on uid/gid )

Tags: networking, server, permissions, mount, iptables

I need to set a traffic limit for each user , which should be based on the username or group name. I have already tried nethogs software and some similar programs, but they limit the bandwidth.  In addition, the limit should not be based on ip or port or using speed limit

Comment: I would look at setting quotas, but I think you might check out this thread on serverfault
https://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth#_=_